# Mongo: How to group the documents has createdAt in 7 days from first document found?

Tags: mongodb

I need to group the documents base on a field with value is a Datetime, from first document found, I need to group all documents of next 7 days, Ex: First document found on 2023-01-01 -> group all documents from 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-07, if 2023-01-08 have any document, continue group from 2023-01-08 to 2023-01-15, else ignore to next available document, if 2023-01-08 and 2023-01-09 doesn't have data, and 2023-01-10 have one document, so need to group 2023-01-17.

I tried to use `$dateTrunc` but result is not like my expect

```
db.xxxx.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
  {
    $project: {
      truncatedOrderDate: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '2022-11-02',
              format: '%Y-%m-%d',
            },
          },
          unit: 'day',
          binSize: 7,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

It's  really as my expect, because it's group from first document to the previous 7 days, not next 7 days.
Btw, I don't understand why the result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "631ea4cb6afdc81a2ce1446c"
    },
    "truncatedOrderDate": {
      "$date": "2022-10-29T00:00:00Z"
    }
  }
]
```

My input date: 2022-11-02 and truncate 7 days, it should be 2022-10-25, Why it return 10-29